# My sourdough starter split in 2 on the 3rd day. What should I do?

Tags: sourdough, sourdough-starter

I have fed it first after 24h and it grew nicely. And on the 2nd morning after I woke up I saw this:

[image]

Should I keep the upper half? or simply start a new batch?

I have used the following formula: 200ml water, 200 gr 550 flour, and kept it at about 25 degree celcius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourdough during the first few days can show pretty erratic behavior. I wouldn’t worry, just stir and feed as planned. Continuing the culture with just the foamy top would probably also work.

Reasons to start over would be visible mold (fluffy or colorful spots) or if there’s no bubbling. Neither is the case here.

Comment: Thanks!, I continued the feeding with the foamy part and I threw away the maia which was at the bottom. It was a bit less than the actual formula (I usually leave 50% and the foamy part was only 25-30%) but we will see how it is going to evolve :)